# SQL: Rename duplicate filenames by adding 1,2,3... before extension

Tags: sql, duplicates, rename, increment

I'm trying to figure out how to rename the contents of a column which stores a filename. Currently there are duplicates in this field which I'm trying to rename by adding a incremental integer after each duplicate, e.g.

```
ID       | FILENAME
----------------------
1        | file1.ext
2        | file2.ext
3        | file1.ext
4        | file1.ext
5        | file3.ext
6        | file3.ext
7        | file4.ext
```

So in the above example, I want the following to be unique:

```
ID       | FILENAME
----------------------
1        | file1.ext
3        | file1.ext
4        | file1.ext
5        | file3.ext
6        | file3.ext
```

By changing the filenames to:

```
ID       | FILENAME
----------------------
1        | file1-1.ext
3        | file1-2.ext
4        | file1-3.ext
5        | file3-1.ext
6        | file3-2.ext
```

I know how to find the duplicates but I'm not sure how to add increments to just before the extension or how to increment the count in the first place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html) `row_number()` to get the number and `replace` for the [string manipulation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html).
You did not disclose your RDBMS. The following query is tested on PostgreSQL 9.0. MySQL does not support window functions, most other big RDBMS do.

Rename **all filenames**:

```
SELECT id
      ,replace(filename, '.',  
               '-'
               || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY filename ORDER BY id)
               || '.')
FROM   mytbl
```

Only rename **duplicate filenames**:

```
SELECT id
      ,CASE WHEN (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY filename)) > 1 THEN
          replace(filename, '.',  
                  '-'
                  || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY filename ORDER BY id)
                  || '.')
       ELSE filename END AS filename
FROM   mytbl;
```

#### Edit with additionally requested features

This version works with multiple or no dots in the name. Tested in PostgreSQL 9.0.

```
SELECT id
      ,CASE WHEN (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY filename)) > 1 THEN
          regexp_replace(filename
              -- pick the longest string from the start not 
             ,'^([^.]*)'containing a '.'
              -- and replace it with itself + row_number
             ,E'\\1-' || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY filename ORDER BY id))
       ELSE filename END AS filename
FROM   mytbl
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I'm using IBM DB2 and the above seems to work great. Just to add a bit more complexity though :)
1. Some files may have a '.' in their name, as well as the extension, e.g. 'some.file.ext'
2. Some files may not have an extension.

Would I just need to build up on the cases?

Comment: @Brian The optimal string manipulation greatly depends on the actual distribution of filenames and the functions available in DB2. I added another version that does *everything you mentioned* in PostgreSQL 9.0